# Azure Cache - How long will data persist, how to detect restart

Tags: caching, azure

With the Azure Cache service, I am trying to find details of the following aspects of the service:

1. What is the maximum length of time something can be kept in the cache?  I presume it would be until the cache service is restarted;
2. Is there a way to detect that the cache service has been restarted?

My intention is to use Azure Cache to store datasets that are frequently being accessed, and that would be updated / added to over time as data that is incoming into my system is processed.

How would I know / be notified that the cache has restarted (I guess apart from seeing if it is empty) so I could kick off a process to repopulate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find answer to your questions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn386128.aspx

Alright, information on High Availability of the cache service is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn386134.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I had previously reviewed that section of the documentation, but it doesn't provide any additional detail regarding the restart/reset of the cache service (i.e. due to patching, etc).  Notifications seem to be what I want, coupled with Regions I guess.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to the high availability section on MSDN for Azure Cache Service. HTH.

Comment: Accepted the answer.  I'm not sure it fully answers the question (how to detect when a cache is restarted) but I'll concede that you probably don't need to know about it if using High Availability.